# How to replace will work in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have dataframe in which I have to replace certain thing but not with all values. Please help how can achieve. Please see below example-

Example-

```
df:

Col
N//A
P//D
https://cg.com
C//A
```

Final Output-

```
df:

Col
N/A
P/D
https://cg.com
C/A
```

I used `df.replace('//', '/', inplace=True)` but it is replacing all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex with lookbehind to exclude the replacement if the `//` is preceded by `:`:

```
df.replace(r'(?<!:)//', '/', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
              Col
0             N/A
1             P/D
2  https://cg.com
3             C/A
```